# How to customize mouse click?

Tags: 12.10, mouse, settings

I would like to open everything in one mouse click. Where is the setting to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open `Nautilus` file manager (open your Home folder for example), click
`Edit -> Preferences -> Behavior` and enable *Single click to open items*.

Comment: Where is the File Manager?

Comment: Go to your Home folder or Downloads folder. There on the top bar where you get File Edit View Go click on Edit and follow the procedure as above!

Comment: Oh ok, `File Managment Preferences` which in windows/simple terms is Open a folder > File > Preferences. Thanks I found it.